# Loss function for regression - vanishing cross term

Tags: regression

[From PRML Bishop, p:48]

I do not understand how the cross term vanishes in the integration. I have tried writing this out, but it does not really make sense to me.

The same operation happens in "Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning" by Rasmussen/Williams on p.152, but it does not specify it either.

The definition of the expected value here is: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{t} | \mathbf{x}] = \mathbb{E}_t[\mathbf{t} | \mathbf{x}] = \int tp(t | \mathbf{x}) \, d\mathrm{t}$, and $y(\mathbf{x})$ is just any function.

[image]

(As a sidenote, it says "integral over $t$", but shouldn't the integral be over $x$?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition you have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{E}\!\left[ L\right] 
= \int_{ } \int_{ } L( t, y( x)  ) p( x, t) \, dx \, dt 
.\end{aligned}
$$
The middle term inserted back into the integral yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
2\int_{ } \int_{ } (  y( x) \mathbf{E}\!\left[ t | x\right] 
- \mathbf{E}\left[ t | x\right] ^{ 2}
- y( x) t+ \mathbf{E}\!\left[ t| x\right] t)p( x, t) \, dx \, dt 
.\end{aligned}
$$
Now you change the order of summation and compute the integral over $ t$. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{ } \int_{ } y( x) \mathbf{E}\!\left[ t |x\right] p( x, t) \, dt \, dx 
&= \int_{ } y( x) \mathbf{E}\left[ t|x\right] p( x) \, dx 
\\ 
\int_{ } \int_{ } \mathbf{E}\left[ t|x\right] ^{ 2}p( x, t) \, dt \, dx 
&= \int_{ } \mathbf{E}\left[ t|x\right] ^{ 2}p( x) \, dx 
\\ 
\int_{ } \int_{ } y( x) t p( x, t) \, dt \, dx 
&= \int_{ } y( x) p( x) \mathbf{E}\!\left[ t|x\right] \, dx 
\\ 
\int_{ } \int_{ } \mathbf{E}\!\left[ t|x\right] tp( x, t) \, dt \, dx 
&= \int_{ } \mathbf{E}\left[ t|x\right] ^{ 2} p( x) \, dx 
\end{aligned}
$$
using
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \mathbf{E}\!\left[ t|x\right] = \frac{1}{ p( x)  } \int_{ } tp( x, t) \, dt 
.\end{aligned}
$$
As you see, all terms cancel out.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot sense! (Although now I am irrationally angry at the misleading notation where $E[t \mid x]$ is not dependent on the integral over $t$)